# Hot To integrate MS Web-Chat component with Google-Speech-To-Text API?

Tags: javascript, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, google-speech-api

As per Microsoft docs, we can configure Web-Chat component to use our own custom speech recognition as below

```
const speechOptions = {
    speechRecognizer: new YourOwnSpeechRecognizer(),
    speechSynthesizer: new YourOwnSpeechSynthesizer()
  };
```

How can I implement "YourOwnSpeechRecognizer" in JAVASCRIPT ??

Answer (score 0):

This is something which you have to do:-

```
export interface ISpeechRecognizer {
    locale: string;
    isStreamingToService: boolean;
    referenceGrammarId: string; // unique identifier to send to the speech implementation to bias SR to this scenario

    onIntermediateResult: Func<string, void>;
    onFinalResult: Func<string, void>;
    onAudioStreamingToService: Action;
    onRecognitionFailed: Action;

    warmup(): void;
    setGrammars(grammars?: string[]): void;
    startRecognizing(): Promise<void>;
    stopRecognizing(): Promise<void>;
    speechIsAvailable(): boolean;
}
```

You have to provide your own custom speech recognition that implements ISpeechRecognizer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: let me check in my code trunk, will get back to you.

Comment: Check out this thread and see if this helps. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1216